# submit button not work

Tags: buttons

i try make 2 submit button in admin post edit page i try this

```
function extra_fields_box_func2( $post ){
     $user = get_current_user_id();
     $change_user = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'change_author', true);
     if ($user==$change_user){
          echo'<form method="post">';
          echo'<input type="submit" name="save" value="Принять" />';
          echo'<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Отклонить" />';
          echo'</form>';
          if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
             error_log('save');
             $res='yes';
            }
          else
          if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
              error_log('delete');
              $res='no';
            }
          if (isset($res)){
          changenotice($post_id, $res);
          }
        }
}
```

and i try this code

```
function extra_fields_box_func2( $post ){
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Принять" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Отклонить" />
</form>
<?php
     $user = get_current_user_id();
     $change_user = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'change_author', true);
     if ($user==$change_user){
          //echo'<form method="post">';
          //echo'<input type="submit" name="save" value="Принять" />';
          //echo'<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Отклонить" />';
          //echo'</form>';
          if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
             error_log('save');
             $res='yes';
            }
          else
          if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
              error_log('delete');
              $res='no';
            }
          if (isset($res)){
          changenotice($post_id, $res);
          }
        }
}
```

but is not work, debug.log is empty, what i make wrong ?

Comment: im try use this code `echo'<form method="post" action="'.get_edit_post_link().'">';` but not is work too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add action="" in

```
echo'<form method="post">';
```

change to:

```
echo'<form method="post" action="">';
```

Comment: im try use this code `echo'<form method="post" action="'.get_edit_post_link().'">';` but not is work too

Comment: leave this attribute empty like in my example.

Comment: yes im try, with empty attribute not work too